# How can I run my code in single CPU or any number of CPUs i want in OpenCL with multi-CPU IN LINUX?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

i am working on OpenCL platform with multipl-CPU. How can I run my code in single CPU or any number of CPUs i desire IN LINUX? Is there is any command in OpenCL for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

By default they run in all cores (AMD and Intel implementations).

If you want to limit the amount of cores being used you can use http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubDevices.html . Just partition partition a quadcore into 4 subdevices and use only a single one and thus you are limited to just running in one core. You can make other kinds of partitions too, such as just use 3 cores if you so wish.

Comment: This is also useful if you want to run a kernel in all cpu cores on the same NUMA node, and leverage better caching/memory access of the system.

Comment: Thanx sharpneli for your suggestions.